# Multiple OnClickListener fix

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to have 10 image buttons in one activity and i would like to have all my buttons clicks in this one activity.I have this code which i think is right for my needs but where i am stuck is..In my java code i don't see the intent to open a new activity.

```
   package com.baha.beallhasall;

   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.graphics.Typeface;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
   import android.widget.Button;
   import android.widget.ImageButton;
   import android.widget.TextView;

   public class FirstActivityPage extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.act_one);
    ImageButton btn1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    ImageButton btn2 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
    ImageButton btn3 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(this);
     btn3.setOnClickListener(this);
   }

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.imageButton1:
            break;                // intent ?????//
        case R.id.imageButton2:
            break;
        case R.id.imageButton3:
            break;
    }
    }
   }
```

So image button1 on click is fine but when its clicked nothing happens.
Do i need to implement and intent somewhere to open it. I am clueless at the moment

Something like this that is missing

```
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), FourActivityPage.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
```

Thanks

Comment: what do you want achieve?

Comment: First off, you don't need to implement the onClickListener or call setOnClickListener() from Java code; in your XML file, for each button attribute, you should be able to add android:onClick="onClick", which will automatically call the onClick method in your Activity.  The way you have that method and the switch statements set up is correct.  All you have to do is put the Intent and startActivity() code you posted in the case statements to get what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement pretty much exactly what you say that it missing.

Depending on the image that was clicked (your `switch-case` statement) you should declare an `Intent` and start it

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivityPage.this, SecondActivityPage.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

[More info here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17598355/open-multiple-listview-item-click-to-one-class   This made things much easyer for me if anyone comes across this code..